# Mix field and js functions when querying Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Look at this document:

```
{
"creation_date" : ISODate("2015-02-10T03:00:00.000Z"),
"days_of_validity": 10
}
```

I'm trying to query all documents where

```
"creation_date" < today -  "days_of_validity"
```

This is my best effort so far:

```
docs.find({"creation_date": 
{$lt:  new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - days_of_validity)}})
```

The thing is that apparently I can't mix js functions with mongo fields.

Any ideas on how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I tried some more calculation hope so this will help you

```
    db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$project": {
    "crationTimestamp": {
        "$subtract": [{
            "$divide": [{
                "$subtract": ["$creation_date", new Date("1970-01-01")]
            }, 1]
        }, {
            "$mod": [{
                "$divide": [{
                    "$subtract": ["$creation_date", new Date("1970-01-01")]
                }, 1]
            }, 1]
        }]
    },
    "days_of_validity": "$days_of_validity",
    "todayTimeStamp": {
        "$subtract": [new Date().getTime(), 0]
    },
    "creation_date": "$creation_date"
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "dayDiff": {
        "$multiply": ["$days_of_validity", 24, 60, 60, 1000]
    },
    "todayTimeStamp": "$todayTimeStamp",
    "crationTimestamp": "$crationTimestamp",
    "days_of_validity": "$days_of_validity",
    "creation_date": "$creation_date"

    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "todayAndDaysDiff": {
        "$subtract": ["$todayTimeStamp", "$dayDiff"]
    },
    "crationTimestamp": "$crationTimestamp",
    "days_of_validity": "$days_of_validity",
    "creation_date": "$creation_date"
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "finalDiff": {
        "$subtract": ["$crationTimestamp", "$todayAndDaysDiff"]
    },
    "days_of_validity": "$days_of_validity",
    "creation_date": "$creation_date"
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
    "finalDiff": {
        "$lt": 0
    }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "days_of_validity": "$days_of_validity",
    "creation_date": "$creation_date"
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying it and I get a
"$err" : "Unsupported projection option: dayDiff"
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: @cgajardo can you try again copy code and replace `collectionName` to your collection name, because it shows me a result without any error and I used mongo `version 2.6.7`.

Answer (score 0):

You have another problem, which is that you're trying to compare one field to another: `days_of_validity` isn't actually a valid variable. You'll need to do an aggregation. Something like this:

```
db.post.aggregate([
    {"$project":{
        "creation_date":1,
        "earliest":{"$subtract":
            [ISODate(), {"$multiply":["$days_of_validity", 1000*3600*24]}]}}},
    {"$project": {"delta": {"$subtract":["$creation_date", "$earliest"]}}},
    {"$match":{"delta": {"$lt": 0}}}])
```

Comment: That's the issue actually, I needed to compare fields while doing some calculations. I'll try doing an aggregation, thanks!